# Why is dereferncing 2 times working and 3 times giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

how does it print element of a 3d array with two dereferencing. i thought it needs something like 3 dereferencing `printf("%c",*(*(*(a+0)+1)+1));`. having an understanding crisis.

```
int main() 
{ 
    char a[2][3][3] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g', 
                           'h','i','j','k','l','m'}; 
    printf("%s ", **a); 
    getchar(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `%s` expects a terminated string. What are you giving it ?

Comment: why **a working @WhozCraig. null character automatically added

Comment: “It doesn’t crash when I run it and looks like it’s doing something sensible” doesn’t mean “it’s working.” %s is wrong, period. Fix that first.

Comment: `printf("%c",*(*(*(a+0)+1)+1));` doesn't cause segmentation fault for me.

Comment: @P.W but ***a causes why

Comment: @givil: ***a is the same as `*(*(*(a+0)+0)+0)`, so it shouldn't. It does not for me. Using `%c`.

Comment: `**a` has type `char [3]`, i.e. a character array .  It decays to `char *` when passed as an argument.  But `***a` has type `char`, which is just an integer type.  It's not a pointer.  It's a single character.  Use `%c` to format a single character, not `%s`.

Comment: The compiler should hopefully complain about sloppy brace style, after which you should fix your initializer list and allocate room for null termination.

Answer (score 0):

The argument supplied for a `%s` specified should be a pointer. For ’%s`,`printf`uses the pointer to fet characters from memory. Therefore, for a three-dimensional array, applying two`*`to the name results in the correct type, a pointer to`char`.

For `%c`, the argument should be an `int` with a character value. Applying three `*` to the array accomplishes this.

Note: Although `**a` provides the correct type for `%s`, the argument is supposed to point to a character in a null-terminated one-dimensional string. Allowing the characters to continue across array dimensions is dodgy.